# Get and Update in a single database query

Tags: database, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with a database that has a list of unused ids, say schema looks like below, with some sample data

```
'unused_id' : '<id1>'
'unused_id' : '<id2>'
...
```

What I want to be able to do is that in my server code. I want to be able to get any of the unused id, and then delete that from the table (or somehow make that unusable for other requests), so that no two requests can use the same unused id at all. I am trying to figure what are the industry standards of dealing with this problem? Given I can have multiple servers, what is the best way? Is there any way to do 'get and delete', or 'get and update (to mark used)' in a single atomic way? Is that the way one would usually do it?

I am currently storing the keys in a dynamodb, but I'm fine to move it to the SQL as well, as this isnt my most used api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DynamoDB you can't do a read and a write atomically. But you can use conditional checks to ensure you don't use the same Id twice.

Get the item from the free ids table and delete it, then conditionally put it as part of a new item to where ever you write to, with a conditional check that it does not exist.

If it does, repeat by reading a new random item and trying again.

- Randomizing the item that you read will reduce conflicts.
- Conditional put will ensure that the first thread to write will win, others will need to retry.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to radomly select from db, and not just scan?

Comment: You can by using a Scan with parameters TotalSegments, Segment and Limit =1. That will give you random result and only read one item.